# Github complete search history

Tags: github

Is there a way to get your complete search history from github. I know when you click the search bar, recent repositories come up from the drop down menu but I cannot find a place where you can look at repository searches aside from that.

Answer (score 0):

You might try this for the future, probably won't load your history before installation

[Chrome add on](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/search-history-for-github/hhfjhjpbgcldkcfhaipdpncfdbohcefa?hl=en)

Comment: This looks at your browser history and I know github keeps track of your history regardless of your browser history. I was hoping there was a way to look at history on github that you deleted from your browser?